# Blur crashes on Tokyo Shutoko loading screen under Win XP

Tags: pc, blur

So far Blur worked fine for me under Windows XP (SP3 32-bit), I managed to beat first boss and start chapter 2. However, just after trying to race on one of the Tokyo Shutoko tracks (presumably Wangan-sen), the game crashes to desktop just after few seconds of loading screen.

I applied some automatic online patches to bring it up to date, tried several different vehicles and various GFX options details, to no avail. I have Core2Duo, GTS 450 and 2 GB of RAM.

Just note it is a non-Steam version of the game (retail).

Is there any known issue with Tokyo tracks in Blur? Is there any possible fixes to such problems?

Comment: 2GB RAM = way too little RAM.

Comment: Actually, it seems 1 GB RAM is fine to run Blur under Win XP. Some sources indicate 2 GB is the recommended amount.

Comment: Crazy question, but do you have the latest drivers (the software not the thing steering the cars)?

Comment: Yea I think I can try it out. I installed the latest as soon as I got the GTS, but might be a good idea to try again. IF it works I will get back to you and ask you to post it as answer and get your bounty :)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help - I tried the latest current drivers. There was a slight difference, as the game did not crash during loading screen, but just after the pre-race presentation started. The frame-rate was crippled and black screen followed, so it seems like a CPU/graphics card related issue.